# PHP Parameter confusion

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am currently learning PHP and using PHP with WordPress. Currently I am limiting the amount of characters comments on my WordPress site can be.

I have a function which uses the hook 'preprocess_comment' .

In the wordpress codex it says preprocess_comment takes one parameter which is an array called $commentdata.

```
function preprocess_comment_handler( $commentdata ) {
    //some code
    return $commentdata;
}
```

The function I am using gives a parameter of $comment

```
function nyt_preprocess_comment($comment) {
    if ( strlen( $comment['comment_content'] ) > 5000 ) {
        wp_die('Comment is too long.');
    }
    return $comment;
}
```

My question is do the parameters not have to have the same name? If not, how come?

Thank you

Comment: No they don't.  The passed parameter's "_value_" is passed to the function, so the "_value_" of that variable is passed to the function parameter and that "_value_" is assigned.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Do you want to put it in an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passed parameters do not have to have the same name.  The passed parameter's "value" is passed to the function, so the "value" of that variable is passed to the function parameter and that "value" is assigned and used in the function.

So in the example the value of `$a` which is `1` is passed to the functions and assigned to `$x` or `$yyyy` respectively:

```
function foo($x) {
    echo $x;
}

function bar($yyyy) {
    echo $yyyy;
}

$a = 1;
foo($a);
bar($a);
```